# Mark Orders Locked for Specfic Date? Difficult Situation

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in trying to decide a method to create the following Functionality:

1. Admin Select Date
2. Admin click Lock Date (Selects all Orders for Date and Marks as Locked)

Now the issue is this, the products are uploaded with a DAY not a DATE.

1. User Selects Day ( clicks one of 7 buttons )
2. places Order for Day

Order is uploaded to Preorders table with the Day that was selected. 
eg, ProductName, ProductImage, Qty(1), Price($15), Day(MON)

How can i select for a specific date and then lock ALL orders on that specific date?

One theory i had is when the user select a product and saves to the table then i should upload with the next DATE where day is the selected day. 
But the issue with this is it would only then save for the 1 day and not all future Mondays for example.

I have the site on a testing server if you would like to take a look please ask and i will give you access.

This is my save to table script:

```
<?php

require '../core/init.php';



    $customerid = $_SESSION['customer_id'];

    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];

    $itemName = $_POST['itemname'];

    $imageName = $_POST['imgname'];

    $qty = $_POST['qty'];

    $price = $_POST['pricetotal'] * $qty;

    $dayofweek = $_POST['dayofweek'];

    $add = DBPDO::getInstance()->insert('standardorder', array(
                'customerId'    => $customerid,
                'itemId'        => $itemid,
                'itemName'      => $itemName,
                'imageName'     => $imageName,
                'qty'           => $qty,
                'price'         => $price,
                'dayOfWeek'     => $dayofweek
            ));


?>
```

Please let me know what other details you need to help you understand the situation.

Thanks

Comment: @dynamic Thanks i added a more relevant title.

Answer (score 0):

Alright as far as I can tell you want to lock in a order that where created on a specific date range. Obviously that is not possible if you don't have a date in your table. So what I suggest is that you add a new column created_at (type: date) in which you save the date the order was created.

The field could be filled on insert with the sql function NOW()

Now you where you know on which date the order was do you can easily select a specific range.

```
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Further you can now query all orders betweend a specific date range and that are for example on a monday

```
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2015-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2015-09-29 10:15:55')
AND dayOfWeek = "MON"
```

Comment: How would i go about saving the record to the table for EVERY Future Date with Day = Mon for example? Eg, table hold preorders so the user will select the product they want and save to table, the admin will the lock the orders for the day. But the product should stay in table until the user remove the order for that day. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps when the admin locks i should not modify the actual row but add the product to real order table. That way the order will not be removed. But the only thing with that is i am unsure how to keep the order to be able to be locked by admin for all future 'Mon'.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully that makes it clearer what I meant.